# using re.findall multple times while iterating through file and list of files

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list

I'm iterating through files in one direcotry. All of them have the same structure:

```
    1.   Site Identification of the GNSS Monument
    
         Site Name                : Aeroport du Raizet -LES ABYMES - Météo France
         Four Character ID        : ABMF
         Monument Inscription     : NONE
    
         ...

    3.   GNSS Receiver Information
    
    3.1  Receiver Type            : ASHTECH UZ-12
         Satellite System         : GPS
         Serial Number            : UC2200303016
         Firmware Version         : CN00
         Elevation Cutoff Setting : 3 deg
         Date Installed           : 2008-07-15T00:00Z
         Date Removed             : 2008-12-29T00:00Z
         Temperature Stabiliz.    : NONE
         Additional Information   : 
    3.2  Receiver Type            : ASHTECH UZ-12
         Satellite System         : GPS
         Serial Number            : UC2200303025
         Firmware Version         : CN00
         Elevation Cutoff Setting : 3 deg
         Date Installed           : 2008-12-29T00:00Z
         Date Removed             : 2009-10-15T20:00Z
         Temperature Stabiliz.    : NONE
         Additional Information   : 

         ...
```

and I want to create list of lists from each file that contain `Four Character ID, Reciever Type, Satellite System, Date Installed, Date Removed` so i created a function:

```
def logs_reader():
    path = Path("C:\\Users\\" + getpass.getuser() + "\\DCBviz\\logs\\")

    cols1 = ['Station ID', 'Reciever type', 'Satellite system', 'Date installed', 'Date removed']
    cols2 = ['Station ID', 'Antenna type', 'Cable length', 'Date installed', 'Date removed']
    
    file_list = [f for f in path.glob('**/*.log') if f.is_file()]
    data = []
    for file in file_list:
        with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
            station_id = re.findall("Four Character ID\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
            receiver_types = re.findall("Receiver Type\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
            
            data.append([station_id, receiver_types, satellite_systems, ......])
    return data

data = logs_reader()
```

but using `re.findall` two times does not work (in exapmle list of station IDs is returned correctly but list of reciever types is empty. How can I fix that?

And second question: Is there a quicker way to create pandas DataFrame with columns named like in `col1` and index beeing `Station ID`?

Comment: The issue is you have `f.read()` twice. The second time used, you have no data to read. The solution is to read the file once into a variable then use that variable in `re.findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `f.read()`, the entire content of the file will be read and returned. The file pointer will reach the end of the file at that point. Therefore, subsequent `f.read()` operations will return an empty string instead.

What you can do is to store the content from `f.read()` as a variable, then pass that variable to `re.findall()`:

```
content = f.read()

station_id = re.findall("Four Character ID\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", content, re.MULTILINE)
receiver_types = re.findall("Receiver Type\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", content, re.MULTILINE)
```